# If $a$ is a discontinuity of $f$, and $g$ is monotone then $g \circ f $ has a discontinuity at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f,g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ . If $a$ is a discontinuity of $f(x)$, and $g(x)$ is monotone then $g \circ f(x) $ has a discontinuity at $a$.

I'm not sure how to prove this. I tried assuming that $g \circ f(x) $ is continuous at $a$,
then for every $x_n \to a$ we have $g(f(x_n)) \to g(f(a))$. Not sure how to continue.

Comment: I haven't checked this rigoursly but here is a thought: what if $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $a$ and $g$ has a jump discontinuity at $f(a)$ by the same amount in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $g$ to be strictly monotonic. Otherwise, $g\equiv 0$ gives a counter-example.

Suppose $g$ is strictly increasing. One of the following holds:

a) There is a sequence $x_n \to a$ and $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x_n) >f(a)+\epsilon$ for all $n$

b) There is a sequence $x_n \to a$ and $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x_n) <f(a)-\epsilon$ for all $n$

In case a) we have $g(f(x_n)) >g(f(a)+\epsilon)$ and $g(f(a)+\epsilon))>g(f(a))$ so $g(f(x_n))$ does not converge to $g(f(a))$

The other cases are similar.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume "monotone" means "strictly monotone," then that means every $x$ is mapped to a distinct $g(x)$ and thus $g$ has a clear inverse.

Thus:
$$g(f(x_n)) \rightarrow g(f(a)$$
$$\iff g^{-1}(g(f(x_n)) \rightarrow g^{-1}(g(f(a))$$
$$\iff f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a),$$
since the inverse gives the Id function,
but this is a contradiction from our hypothesis.